# What is FirebaseCrashlytics equivalent statement of Fabric recordError:error?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

**What is FirebaseCrashlytics equivalent statement of Fabric recordError:error?**

What will be equivalent statement for FirebaseCrashlytics in iOS, of

```
[[Crashlytics sharedInstance] recordError:error];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can find that documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=ios#log-excepts